# How do I install Touchegg in elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation, touchpad

I'm trying to get touchegg working in elementary OS Loki but I'm not able to install all the dependencies for touchpad( synaptics ). I'm using Zenbook UX305. Can some please guide me though the necessary steps to install it properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
Works fine on loki install